# magento enterprise session cache issue

Tags: cache, full-page-cache, toplinks, customer-session

I am working on magento enterprise  **1.14.2.0** and we installed all patches that required.

I am facing issue with cache or session

when customer login to his/her account, Customer name display wrong on top link cart-item count  order and customer profile are ok but name in top link is wrong.

I am using customize template

```
<?php 
     $session = Mage::helper('customer');
     if($session->isLoggedIn()) {
        $customer = $session->getCustomer();
        echo "<p>".$customer->getName()."</p>";
     } 
 ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento EE already has a “hole punch” in place for the logged-in customer name. It sounds like you are not using this built-in block, so double check that your current layout and template is using this block for displaying the customer name:

```
<block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">
    ...
    <block type="page/html_welcome" name="welcome" as="welcome"/>
    ...
</block>
```

You should see it used in your `header.phtml` template, something like this:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('welcome') ?>
```

Here is the placeholder that already exists to handle this block:

**app/code/core/Enterprise/PageCache/etc/cache.xml**

```
<welcome_message>
    <block>page/html_welcome</block>
    <placeholder>WELCOME</placeholder>
    <container>Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Container_Welcome</container>
    <cache_lifetime>86400</cache_lifetime>
</welcome_message>
```

Comment: I am using customize template and customer name come from header.phtm file

Comment: @vaibhavahalpara Okay, that is the issue for sure then. See my update above; you will need to remove your custom implementation and replace it with the `welcome` block output. By default it will say “Welcome, $name!” but you can override that by either extending the `page/html_welcome` block or using the locale file to change that string to `<p>%s</p>`.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to read up on hole punching.

Start here:

[How to hole punch a child block added inside catalog/product/list block](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8481/how-to-hole-punch-a-child-block-added-inside-catalog-product-list-block)

Then this:

https://www.pixafy.com/blog/2013/03/overcoming-magentos-full-page-cache-through-hole-punching/

Familiarize yourself with the Enterprise_PageCache_* classes.  You might be able to just extend some of them.  Although I fixed that particular scenario you have going a while back, it was a little more involved.

I don't have any supporting code at my disposal unfortunately, but this can get you where you need to be. Its not overly difficult once you get into it.